# Use strptime function on vectors only have time

Tags: r, strptime

I have a data frame with two columns containing date and time data, and I want to convert the time data using strptime function

```
date<-c("2007-1-1", "2007-1-2", "2007-1-3")
time<-c("00:00:00", "00:00:05", "00:00:10")
dat<-data.frame(date, time)
```

I can use as. Date to convert date column, however when I use strptime to convert time column, it shows

```
strptime(dat$time, "%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2014-12-03 00:00:00 PST" "2014-12-03 00:00:05 PST" "2014-12-03 00:00:10 PST"
```

How can I get rid of "2014-12-03"? Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to be a POSIXt date-time?

Comment: I think he's saying he wants times, with no representation of date whatsoever.

Comment: I thought that as well, but he's already got that

Comment: Thanks, Richard. I am new to R so I am learning a lot of things. Yes, I want it to be a POSIXlt format and strptime includes all the information about the date and time. So I just paste the two columns together then use strptime

Comment: The answer to this question is included in the accepted answer to [Convert 12 hour character time to 24 hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833538/convert-12-hour-character-time-to-24-hour)