# NA value when using strptime() to convert from 12 hr format to 24 hr format in R

Tags: r, strptime

I have a data frame with a column of dates/times in a 12 hour timestamp format (`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`). I would like to change these to a 24 hour/ military time format (`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`).

I have tried using `strptime(times, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")`. This works for the majority of the rows in the column, but some are returning `NA`. I went and looked at the original 12 hour time for the rows returning `NA` and they are a correct date format, and the same as the rest. I am not sure why I am getting `NA` for some of the values, or how to fix this error.

Anyone know why I am getting `NA` values and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Update: I've noticed that all the dates that are returning `NA` either contain 2 AM or 2 PM. I'm not sure why that would be causing an issue though.

Comment: Can you post a dataset example with the problem dates? With `dput(problem dates)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Here are a couple of the dates that return NA:
`3/12/2017 2:17:56 AM` `3/12/2017 2:58:41 PM` `3/11/2018 2:55:25 PM`

Comment: For `times <- c('3/12/2017 2:17:56 AM', '3/12/2017 2:58:41 PM', '3/11/2018 2:55:25 PM')`, `strptime(times, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")` gives the expected results for me.

Comment: To get 24 hour time, I think you need to use `%I` and `%p` instead of `%H`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833538/convert-12-hour-character-time-to-24-hour

Comment: @divibisan Using `%I` and `%p` instead of `%H`does result in less `NA` values, but I am still getting some.
I'm working with about 568,000 rows and now I'm getting 22 `NA` instead of 61.

Comment: Can you update your question with the corrected format string and provide a list of those 22 NA rows?