# How to convert a 12 hour time stamp (NOT a datetime, time only) to 24 hour time?

Tags: r, date, datetime, time, lubridate

I have a **character** column containing times in the 12 hour format, for example: 2:59:00 PM, 4:35:00 AM, 6:00:00 PM, etc.

How can I convert these to 24 hour time using lubridate (or some other function)? I tried using the HMS functions but it just strips the AM/PM without actually converting the time to 24 hour time...

**EDIT:** I tried the answer from this post: [Convert 12 hour character time to 24 hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833538/convert-12-hour-character-time-to-24-hour)

This was my code: lab_data[,LAB_TM_test:=format(strptime(LAB_TM, "%I:%M %p"), format="%H:%M:%S")]

But this results in my column becoming all NA and gives me this warning:

"Warning message:
In strptime(LAB_TM, "%I:%M %p") :
strptime() usage detected and wrapped with as.POSIXct(). This is to minimize the chance of assigning POSIXlt columns, which use 40+ bytes to store one date (versus 8 for POSIXct). Use as.POSIXct() (which will call strptime() as needed internally) to avoid this warning."

**EDIT2:** Here is what my column looks like, it is a character column:

[image]

c("2:59:00 PM", "4:35:00 AM", "6:00:00 PM", "6:00:00 PM", "6:00:00 PM",
"6:00:00 PM", "6:00:00 PM", "6:00:00 PM", "5:35:00 AM")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert 12 hour character time to 24 hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833538/convert-12-hour-character-time-to-24-hour)

Comment: Hi, I tried this previously but it does not work, it results in all NA in my column. This is what I tried: lab_data[,LAB_TM_test:=format(strptime(LAB_TM, "%I:%M %p"), format="%H:%M:%S")]    but this just results in NAs

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: Sure thing I've edited my post

Comment: Try to use `dput(lab_data[1:9, LAB_TM])` instead of picture, which we can't copy.

Comment: Sorry, just added it! Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
lab_data[,LAB_TM_test:=as.POSIXct(LAB_TM, format='%I:%M:%S %p')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a **base R** solution, using `strptime` to convert to 24h-format and `strftime` to only print the time.

```
df$LAB_TM_new <- strftime(strptime(df$LAB_TM, format="%I:%M:%S %p"), format="%H:%M:%S")

df
      LAB_TM LAB_TM_new
1 2:59:00 PM   14:59:00
2 4:35:00 AM   04:35:00
3 6:00:00 PM   18:00:00
4 6:00:00 PM   18:00:00
5 6:00:00 PM   18:00:00
6 6:00:00 PM   18:00:00
7 6:00:00 PM   18:00:00
8 6:00:00 PM   18:00:00
9 5:35:00 AM   05:35:00
```