# Convert time string with both am/pm and 24 hour format in R

Tags: r

I have a list of times in my `df` column like so:

```
times <- c("11:30am", "3:15pm", "2:25pm", "12:05pm", "8:25pm", "7:52pm", "13:22", "18:45", "21:14", "11:20")
```

How can I convert the times to time format so they are all formatted correctly?

I would like the am/pm to be removed from those that have it and converted to 24 hr time, and for those that are already in the correct format, to be converted to time format.
Desired output:

```
11:30
15:15
14:25
12:05
20:25
19:52
13:22
18:45
21:14
11:20
```

I tried:

```
times <- ifelse(grepl('am', times) | grepl('pm', times),
                  as.POSIXct(times, format = "%I:%M%p"), as.POSIXct(times,format="%H:%M"))
```

But it just gave me a list of numbers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29833538/1315767

Comment: this works for 'am/pm' values but does not convert the times already in the H:M format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```r
sapply(strsplit(times, ":"), function(x) {
  h <- as.numeric(x[1]) + grepl("pm", x[2]) * 12
  if(h == 24) h <- 12
  if(h == 12 & grepl("am|pm", x[2])) h <- 0
  paste(sprintf("%02d", h), 
        gsub("^(\\d+).*$", "\\1", x[2]), sep = ":")
})
#>  [1] "11:30" "15:15" "14:25" "00:05"  "20:25" "19:52" "13:22" "18:45"
#>  [9] "21:14" "11:20"
```

Comment: thank you. This worked but for times that are at or after midnight, such as 12:00am or 12:15am or 00:00 or 00:15 (I know my OP didn't have any of these), they display as 0:00 or 0:15. Can I get these with a leading 0, such as 00:00 or 00:15?

Comment: @Michael sure - see my update. This will give you a fixed 2-digit hour and 2-digit minute output

Comment: actually there is one more condition I forgot to mention in my OP. If the time does not have 'am/pm' but has 12 as the hour, say 12:05 or 12:40, these are converted above as 00:05 and 00:40 when in fact they should be 12:05 and 12:40?

Comment: @Michael you're right - should be fixed now

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular expression to detect the format of the input value.

Then adjust the argument of `strptime` depending on the hour input format.

```
ifelse(grepl("am|pm", times),
       format(strptime(times, "%I:%M %p"), format="%H:%M"),
       format(strptime(times, "%H:%M"), format="%H:%M"))
```

```
[1] "11:30" "15:15" "14:25" "12:05" "20:25" "19:52" "13:22" "18:45" "21:14" "11:20"
```

Comment: It works for me with `strptime` from `base` version 4.2.1

Comment: it worked but on my bigger data set (~ 1M rows), it displays many NA values , I am not sure why.

Comment: Might have to force a `strptime(..., tz="UTC")` to make sure you don't hit any daylight savings issues in your current timezone.

Comment: Could you provide an example of input time value that outputs an NA?

Answer (score 0):

Using `parse_date`

```
library(parsedate)
format(parse_date(times), "%H:%M")
```

-output

```
[1] "11:30" "15:15" "14:25" "12:05" "20:25" "19:52" "13:22" "18:45" "21:14" "11:20"
```